# Save form data into database and upload file into dropbox in node.js express

Tags: ajax, node.js

I want to save my form data into database and upload same form file into dropbox.

I could upload files into dropbox separately using formidable, I couldn't combine the both.

Thanks in advance!!

**HTML Form:**

```
    <form id="content" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>New Content</legend>
    title : <input type="text" name="tit" id="tit"/><br><br>
    category : <input type="text" name="cat" id="cat"/><br><br>
    description : <input type="text" name="des" id="des"/><br><br>
    file : <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><br><br>
    <div class="resu"></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**Ajax Request:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content').submit(function(event) {

       var title              = $('input[name=tit]').val();
       var category           = $('input[name=cat]').val();
       var desc           = $('input[name=des]').val();
       var file    = $('input[name=file]').val();
        var filename = file.split("\\").pop(); 
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/addContent',
        data        : {"user_id": 12,  "title": title, "description": desc, "category": category, "file_name": filename}, 
        dataType    : 'application/json', 
        encode      : true,
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            //$(.result).html(data);
            console.log(data); 
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

**Node.Js File**

```
router.post("/", function(req, res){

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    //console.log(files);
    // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`
    var temp_path = files.file.path,
        file_type = files.file.type,
        file_name = files.file.name;
        //new_path = 'uploads/';

    node_dropbox.Authenticate(app_key, app_secret, 'redirect_url', function(err, url){
        //console.log(url);
    });

    node_dropbox.AccessToken(app_key, app_secret, 'access_code', 'redirect_url', function(err, body) {
        var access_token = body.access_token;
        var token = token;
        var api = node_dropbox.api(token);

        fs.readFile(temp_path, function(err,content){
            if(!err){
                request.put('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/files/upload/' + file_name, {
                headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': file_type}, 
                body: content}, 
                function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Not Uploaded');
                        res.end();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Uploaded Successfully");
                        var query="INSERT INTO kind_heart.contents(user_id, title, category, description, content_status, date_time, file_name) VALUES(?,?,?,?,'Uploaded',NOW(),?)";
                        var datafromjson = [req.body.user_id, req.body.title, req.body.category, req.body.description, req.body.file_name];
                        console.log("SQL Query: " + query);
                        connection.query(query, datafromjson, function(err, rows, fields) {
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log("Error: Not Uploaded");
                                res.end("Error: Not Uploaded");
                            }else{      
                                //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                                var result = JSON.stringify(rows);
                                res.end(result);
                                console.log("Uploaded Succesfully!!");
                            }
                        });                         
                        res.end();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

});